# simulate a random number in r for an unknown distribution

Tags: r, random, simulation

I am trying to simulate random numbers for an unknown distribution in R. I know random number generation functions like rnorm, runif and others are used for known distributions. My input data is a revenue data of 4 years with about 500 rows. I want to generate 10 random numbers for this revenue distribution.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at `?sample` ...

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a data frame, you use `sample` to randomly sample entire years.

```
df = data.frame(year1 = c(50,100,500), year2 = c(200, 500, 1000), year3 = c(250, 80, 99), year4=c(400, 5000, 98750))
sample(df, 2)
  year2 year4
1   200   400
2   500  5000
3  1000 98750
```

If you data is in a matrix, you can use `sample` to randomly sample single entries

```
mat = matrix(rbind(c(50,100,500), c(200, 500, 1000), c(250, 80, 99),c(400, 5000, 98750)), ncol = 4)
sample(mat, 5)
[1] 5000   99  200  500   80
```

Comment: or `sample(df$revenue_stream,2, replace=TRUE)` if you want to sample from a particular column (sampling with replacement probably makes more sense for the OP's use case)